# Suppose $E[X_1] <\infty$. Show that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{X_n}{S_n}=0$ a.s.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, law-of-large-numbers

Let $X_1,X_2,X_3,...$ be i.i.d. with $P(X_1 >0)=1$. Define $S_n =\Sigma_{i=1}^{n} X_i$.

(a) Suppose $\mathbb{E}[X_1] <\infty$. Show that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{X_n}{S_n}=0$ a.s.

I think here $\frac{X_n}{S_n}=\frac{n}{S_n}\times \frac{X_n}{n}$ and $\frac{X_n}{n}\rightarrow 0$ because here $X_n$ is a $L^{1}$ function. I don't think it's rigorous, or may be even wrong.

(b) Constrct an example in which $\mathbb{E}[X_1] =\infty$ and $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{X_n}{S_n}=0$ a.s is false.

No idea about the second part.

Comment: (a) Use $\Bbb E[X_1]<\infty$ to show $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\Bbb P[X_n/n>\epsilon]<\infty$ for each $\epsilon>0$, then invoke First Borel Cantelli.

Comment: @JohnDawkins Did you know how to do the second part?